# JTree is not filtering extensions

Tags: java, swing, file, tree, jtree

I'm stuck on this problem:

I have a JTree which shows the whole directory and its children, but I need to filter it to show only the directories and files with some extensions (e.g. ".m", ".py").

```
package classes;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class FileTree implements TreeModel{
private File root;
private Vector listeners = new Vector();

public FileTree(File rootDirectory){
    root = rootDirectory;
}

@Override
public Object getRoot(){
    return root;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(Object parent, int index){
    File directory = (File) parent;
    String[] children = directory.list(new FilenameFilter(){
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
            return name.endsWith(".m") || dir.isDirectory();
        }           
    });
    return new FileTree.TreeFile(directory, children[index]);
}

@Override
public int getChildCount(Object parent){
    File file = (File) parent;
    if (file.isDirectory()){
        String[] fileList = file.list();          
        if (fileList != null){
            return file.list().length;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean isLeaf(Object node){
    File file = (File) node;
    return file.isFile();
}

@Override
public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child){
    File directory = (File) parent;
    File file = (File) child;
    String[] children = directory.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
        if (file.getName().equals(children[i])){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

@Override
public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object value){
    File oldFile = (File) path.getLastPathComponent();
    String fileParentPath = oldFile.getParent();
    String newFileName = (String) value;
    File targetFile = new File(fileParentPath, newFileName);
    oldFile.renameTo(targetFile);
    File parent = new File(fileParentPath);
    int[] changedChildrenIndices = {getIndexOfChild(parent, targetFile)};
    Object[] changedChildren = {targetFile};
    fireTreeNodesChanged(path.getParentPath(), changedChildrenIndices, changedChildren);
}

private void fireTreeNodesChanged(TreePath parentPath, int[] indices, Object[] children){
    TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, parentPath, indices, children);
    Iterator iterator = listeners.iterator();
    TreeModelListener listener = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        listener = (TreeModelListener) iterator.next();
        listener.treeNodesChanged(event);
    }
}

@Override
public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener){
    listeners.add(listener);
}

@Override
public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener listener){
    listeners.remove(listener);
}

private class TreeFile extends File{

    public TreeFile(File parent, String child){
        super(parent, child);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getName();
    }
  }
}
```

And in my `main()` method, I call it like

```
JTree tree = new JTree();
tree.setModel(new FileTree(new File("\\C:\\")));
treePanel.setViewportView(tree);
```

I think the problem is in `getChild()` method, however I just can figure it out how to solve it.

Are there any differences between `file.list()` and `file.listFiles()` methods? Because I have already used both and still don't get it.

EDIT: After following @Thomas suggestions, now it shows me this error:

PS: When I print "children" variable on `getChild()` method in order to debug, it returns me all directories(there are 14) in "C:\".

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 14

The updated methods:

```
    @Override
public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child){
    File directory = (File) parent;
    File file = (File) child;
    String[] children = directory.list(new FilenameFilter(){
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
            return name.endsWith(".m") || new File(dir, name).isDirectory();
        }
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
        if (file.getName().equals(children[i])){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and

```
    @Override
public int getChildCount(Object parent){
    File file = (File) parent;
    if (file.isDirectory()){
        String[] fileList = file.list(new FilenameFilter(){
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
                return name.endsWith(".m") || new File(dir, name).isDirectory();
            }
        });          
        if (fileList != null){
            return file.list().length;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"And in my `main()` method, I call it like.."* For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your implementation of the `FilenameFilter`.

The javadoc for the `FilenameFilter#accept` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html#accept-java.io.File-java.lang.String-) method describes the parameters:

- dir - the directory in which the file was found.
- name - the name of the file.

From this description it is clear that your accept method:

```
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
        return name.endsWith(".m") || dir.isDirectory();
    }
```

will always return `true`, since dir is always a directory.

If you want to check whether the entry `name` within the directory `dir` is a directory you would have to rewrite your accept method as

```
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
        return name.endsWith(".m") || new File(dir, name).isDirectory();
    }
```

This will give you only the directories and the files with an name ending in ".m".

But now you also need to change your `getChildCount()` and `getIndexOfChild()` methods - because currently they are based on unfiltered child lists.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Thomas. Now I see.. but what changes would be necessary? I don't get it.. another filter in listFiles on those methods?

Comment: @zsp exactly, you will need to apply the same filtering to the `File#list()` method in `getChildCount()` and `getIndexOfChild()`

Comment: I already did that, but it shows an error.. see my edited post, please

Comment: @zsp in the `getChildCount()` you first create a filtered list `fileList = ...` but then you `return file.list().length;` - i.e. the length of the unfiltered list. Instead you should write `return fileList.length;`